# What is the "Rails way" to do correlated subqueries?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, correlated-subquery

I asked [nearly the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267772/correlated-subquery-in-activerecord-or-squeel) in probably the wrong way, so I apologize for both the near duplicate and lousy original phrasing.  I feel like my problem now is attempting to fight Rails, which is, of course, a losing battle.  Accordingly, I am looking for the idiomatic Rails way to do this.

I have a table containing rows of user data which is scraped from a third party site periodically.  The old data is just as important as the new data; the old data is, in fact, probably used more often.  There are no performance concerns about referencing the new data, because only a couple people will ever use my service (I keep my standards realistic).  But thousands of users are scraped periodically (i.e., way too often).  I have named the corresponding models "User" and "UserScrape"

Table `users` has columns: `id`, `name`, `email`

Table `user_scrapes` has columns: `id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `address_id`, `awesomesauce_preference`

Note: *These are not the real models - user_scrapes has a lot more columns - but you probably get the point*

At any given time, I want to find *the most recent* `user_scrapes` values associated with the data retrieved from an external source from a given user.  I want to find out that my current `awesomeauce_preference` is, because lately it's probably 'lamesauce' but before, it was 'saucy_sauce'.

I want to have a convenient method that allows me to access the newest scraped data for each user in such a way that I can combine it with separate `WHERE` clauses to narrow it down further.  That's because in at least a dozen parts of my code, I need to deal with the data from the latest scrape.

What I have done so far is this horrible hack that selects the latest `user_scrapes` for each user with a regular `find_by_sql` correlated sub-query, then I `pluck` out the `id`s of the scrapes, then I put an additional `where` clause in any relevant query (that needs the latest data).

This is already an issue performance-wise because I don't want to buffer over a million integers (yes, a lot of pages get scraped very often) then try to pass the MySQL driver a list of these and have it miraculously execute a perfect query plan.  In my benchmark it took almost as long as it did for me to write this post, so I lied before.  Performance is *sort of* an issue, but not really.

**My question**

So with my `UserScrape` class, how can I make a method called 'current', as in: `UserScrape.find(1337).current.where(address_id: 1234).awesomesauce_preference` when I live at addresses 1234 and 1235 and I want to find out what my `awesomsauce_preference` is at my latest address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are scopes:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

In particular, you can probably use:

```
scope :current, order("user_scrapes.created_at DESC").limit(1)
```

**Update:**

Scopes are meant to return an ActiveRecord object, so that you can continue chaining methods if you wish.  There is nothing to prevent you (last I checked anyways) from writing this instead, however:

```
scope :current, order("user_scrapes.created_at DESC").first
```

This returns just the one object, and is not chainable, but it may be a more useful function ultimately.

```
UserScrape.where(address_id: 1234).current.awesomesauce_preference
```

Comment: So then if I want a Hash of { user_id: awesomesauce_preference }, how do I get that?  If I just use UserScrape.current, I get an array of one row.

Comment: I've updated the answer (only 4 months late). The exact hash you're looking for you would have to construct yourself from the awesomesauce_preference you get above, i.e. `{awesomesauce_preference.user_id => awesomesauce_preference}`.

Comment: A) how is this a correlated subquery? B) why not just use a self.method rather than scope, if you're looking for a single record? `def self.current self.order('created_at DESC').first end` and then just, like, `User.user_scrapes.current.awesomesauce_preference` or whatever? Or even put it on `User`, `def current_scrape user_scrapes.order('created_at DESC').first end`

Comment: @BenSaufley The main reason you would use a scope rather than a static method is because the scope can be called from an ActiveRecord relation object of the proper table if you want (i.e., chained from previous scope calls), and the static method can only be called when starting from the model name.  For example, what I wrote above, `UserScrape.where(address_id: 1234).current.awesomesauce_preference` would not have worked with a static method. Even your example, `User.user_scrapes.current.awesomesauce_preference`, does not work with a static method to my knowledge, but would work with a scope.

Comment: This isn't a correlated subquery.